# I haven't seen that number before!

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

Write a program that goes through a string of non-whitespace characters (you may assume that they are digits `0` to `9`, but nothing in the way they are to be processed depends on this) and adds spaces according to the following rules.

1. Let the current token be the empty string, and the previously emitted tokens be an empty set.
2. Iterate through the characters of the string. For each character, first append the character to the current token. Then if the current token is not already in the set of previously emitted tokens, add the current token to that set and let the new current token be the empty string.
3. If when you reach the end of the string the current token is empty, output the previously emitted tokens in order of emission, separated by a space character. Otherwise output the original string verbatim.

**Input**

The input to the STDIN should be a sequence of digits.

**Output**

The program should print the result as specified in step 3.

**Samples**

*Sample inputs*

```
2015
10101010
4815162342
101010101010
3455121372425
123456789101112131415
314159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937
```

*Sample outputs*

```
2 0 1 5
10101010
4 8 1 5 16 2 3 42
1 0 10 101 01 010
3 4 5 51 2 1 37 24 25
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
3 1 4 15 9 2 6 5 35 8 97 93 23 84 62 64 33 83 27 95 0 28 841 971 69 39 937
```

---

This is code golf, so standard CG rules apply. Shortest program in bytes wins.

(Please request any clarifications in the comments. I'm still new to this. Thanks!)

Comment: `4815162342` I see what you did there, *brotha*.

Comment: I suggest to get rid of the “repeat at the end of the number” part of rule 7. (It confused me too.) Maybe you could say, there are not enough digits to form a distinct number.

Comment: Probable error in the spec: step 6 asks us to repeat steps 3 and 4, so the only number in the output which can be more than one digit long is the second one. If that were to be corrected simply by changing it to "*Repeat steps 4 and 5 ...*", the movement in step 5 would mean that each number in the output should have an odd number of digits. And numbers which have leading zeroes are equal to the number without the leading zeroes, so if you want to distinguish `01` from `1` you should stop talking about numbers altogether and talk about strings instead.

Comment: A test case which my code originally failed despite passing all the ones in the challenge: `11312123133`

Comment: Proposed OEIS entry: numbers which are split into at least two segments by this process.

Comment: @Sok Notice that `10101010` can result in `1 0 10 1010`, which fits the rules.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Step 5 (as any other step) can only advance _one_ digit at a time. Once you’ve got `1 0 10 `, the next iteration will find `1` (already used), then advance one to find `10` (already used), then advance one to find `101`, which is new and would be ‘added’. It would then add a space and you'd get to a new `0`, which has already been used, but is here at the end of the string. Therefore, the output would be `1 0 10 101 0`, which is invalid (`0` is repeated), and the script must then just output the input string. It could only make `1010` if `101` had already been used.

Comment: You list `10101010` as an output. That looks like a mistake.

Comment: @kasperd No `If a unique number cannot be formed at the end of the string, then the input should be printed verbatim` 10101010  cannot be split so it is printed as is.

Comment: @edc65 I see. I had misunderstood that rule.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, no. Given input `10101010` steps 1 to 3 give `1 ^0101010` (with `^` to indicate the position of the cursor); then step 4 gives `1 0^101010`, step 5 gives `1 0 ^101010`; step 4 gives `1 0 1^01010`; step 5 gives `1 0 10^1010`; step 4 gives `1 0 101^010`; step 5 gives `1 0 101 ^010`; step 4 gives `1 0 101 0^10`; step 5 gives `1 0 101 01^0`; step 4 gives `1 0 101 010^`; step 5 gives `1 0 101 010`; and the loop breaks. So the specified output for that input is `1 0 101 010`

Comment: @PeterTaylor No. `10` has not been used yet at `1 0 10^1010`, so it wouldn't continue to `1 0 101^010`, but add a space, making `1 0 10 ^1010`. Moving on to `101` doesn't happen until the next ‘group of 10’ when it reaches `1 0 10 101^0`.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, step 5 doesn't have a self-loop. It either inserts a space or moves one right. Then you go back to step 4. That's why I pointed out in my first comment that the spec requires each generated part to have an odd number of digits.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Exactly. It adds a space _if doing so creates a number which has not already been used_. At the relevant position, `10` has not yet been used, so step 5 adds a space and does not move to the right. I don't see how that would imply that the output must be an odd number of digits.

Comment: But when you *enter* step 5, the space would be after the `1`, which would be a repeat. So instead you move right one in space 5, and then you move right one again in step 4, and you enter step 5 again and create `101`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Aaah, yes. I see what you mean now. Really, step 4 should be done away with entirely, and step 5 should be the only repeated one. Well spotted! (Really, steps 2 through 4 can _all_ be scrapped, since the first digit will always be unused the first time it's reached.)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Looks like you beat me to the editing. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Pyth, 22 bytes

```
 faW!}=+kTYY~kdz?tkzsY
```

Leading space is important.

Answer (score 13):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>68</s> 61 bytes

```
+`\b(\w+?)(?<!\b\1 .*)(\w+)$
$1 $2
(?=.* (.+)$(?<=\b\1 .+)) 
<empty>
```

`<empty>` is an empty line. Note the trailing space on line 3. You can run the above code from a single file with the `-s` flag.

### Explanation

```
+`\b(\w+?)(?<!\b\1 .*)(\w+)$
$1 $2
```

This first step implements rules 1 to 6. It is a regex substitution which is applied repeatedly until the string stops changing (that's what the `+` is for). In each step we add a single space into the string from left to right (following the rules of the challenge). The regex matches the shortest string of digits which hasn't appeared in the already processed part of the string. We ensure that we're looking at a prefix of the remaining string with the word boundary `\b` and checking that we can reach the end of the string without passing spaces with `(\w+)$`. The latter also ensures that we only perform one replacement per step.

```
(?=.* (.+)$(?<=\b\1 .+)) 
<empty>
```

This matches any space (which is at the end of the regex), provided that the last segment of the string is the same as any other segment in the string, and replaces them with the empty string. That is, we undo the first step if it resulted in an invalid final segment, implementing rule 7.

Answer (score 11):

### Pyth, <del>24</del> 23 bytes

```
VzI!}=+kNYaY~k"";?kzjdY
```

Try it out [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VzI%21%7D%3D%2BkNYaY~k%22%22%3B%3FkzjdY&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2015%0A10101010%0A4815162342%0A101010101010%0A3455121372425%0A123456789101112131415%0A314159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937&debug=0).

```
VzI!}=+kNYaY~k"";?kzjdY    Implicit: z=input(), k='', Y=[], d=' '
Vz              ;          For N in z:
     =+kN                    Append N to k
  I!}    Y                   Is the above not in Y?
          aY k               Append k to Y
            ~k""             After append, reset k to ''
                 ?k        Is k truthy (i.e. not '')
                   z       Print original input
                    jdY    Otherwise print Y joined on spaces
```

Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for saving a byte :o)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman A good call, I got pretty caught up in trying to preserve k's original value

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 92 bytes

```
i,n,*o=input(),""
for c in i:n+=c;o,n=[o+[n],o,"",n][n in o::2]
print([" ".join(o),i][n>""])
```

Basically a heavily golfed version of @Willem's solution.

Comment: `[" ".join(o),i][n>""]`

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Ah cool, I had tried that with `bool(n)` but I didn't think of `n>""`.

Answer (score 6):

### Python 3, <s>100</s> 99 bytes

```
o=[];n="";i=input()
for c in i:
 n+=c
 if not n in o:o.append(n);n=""
print(i if n else" ".join(o))
```

Comment: I fixed your byte count. Also, you should remove the space from `else "`.

Comment: [Some common golfs](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#o%3D%5B%5D%3Bn%3D%22%22%3Bi%3Dinput%28%29%0Afor%20c%20in%20i%3A%0A%20n%2B%3Dc%0A%20if%28n%20in%20o%29-1%3Ao.append%28n%29%3Bn%3D%22%22%0Aprint%28%5B%22%20%22.join%28o%29%2Ci%5D%5Bn%3E%22%22%5D%29) Also, your original score was 100 bytes, I think.

Comment: Cool thanks! I didn't know that the space after "else" could be removed. Another day lived, another day learned :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 91 bytes

```
:_:_{h:0<|bhN,?hh:NrcH,?hB(l1,-1=A;BbA),?rhL:I(mH:Ar:[L]c:1&;:[H]:\"~w \"w,L:[H]c:_:Ar:1&)}
```

This made me realize that there's a lot of things about the syntax I need to change...

#### Explanation

```
:_:_              § Creates a list [Input,[],[]] 
{...}             § Define a new predicate between the brackets and call it with the previous list as input
h:0<              § If the head of the input is negative, stop
|                 § Else
bhN,              § Second element of Input is called N
?hh:NrcH,         § N concatenated with the first element of Input is H
?hB(l1,-1=A;BbA), § Remaining digits A are either -1 if there's only one digit left or all the digits but the head otherwise
?rhL:I            § List of used integers is called L
(
   mH:Ar:[L]c:1&  § If H is already in L, call the predicate with input [A,H,L]
   ;              § Else
   :[H]:\"~w \"w, § Print H followed by a space
   L:[H]c:_:Ar:1& § Call the predicate with input [A,[],M] where M is L with H appended to it
)
```

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 26 bytes

```
LLq{+_a2$&{a+L}|}/:X+X!S**
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=LLq%7B%2B_a2%24%26%7Ba%2BL%7D%7C%7D%2F%3AX%2BX!S**&input=314159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937)

### Explanation

```
L        e# Push an empty array to keep track if the previous segments.
L        e# Push an empty array to build the current segment.
q{       e# For each character in the input...
  +      e#   Add it to the current segment.
  _a2$&  e#   Duplicate and check if it's already in the segment list.
  {      e#   If not...
    a+L  e#     Add it to the list and push a new empty array for the next segment.
  }|
}/
:X+      e# Store the trailing segment in X and add it's *characters* to the list.
         e# For valid splittings, this trailing segment will be empty, so that the
         e# list remains unchanged.
X!       e# Push X again and take the logical NOT.
S*       e# Get that many spaces, i.e. 1 for valid segments and 0 otherwise.
*        e# Join the list with this string between elements.
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 109

My output format is not exactly the same of the output samples in the questioin (there is a leading space). I don't see that as a flaw, as the output format is not specified (just *The program should print the number after the number...*)

Test running the snippet below in a EcmaScript 6 compliant browser. Developed with Firefox, tested and running on the latest Chrome.

```js
/* Test: redirect console.log */ console.log=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n';

F=s=>{for(z=s,b=l=o=' ';s[+l];)~o.search(b+(n=s.slice(0,++l)+b))||(s=s.slice(l),o+=n,l=0);console.log(s?z:o)}

/* Test cases */
test = [
  '2015',
,'10101010'
,'4815162342'
,'101010101010'
,'3455121372425'
,'123456789101112131415'
,'11312123133'
,'314159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937']

test.forEach(t=>{console.log('\n'+t);F(t)})
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## GNU sed, <strike>83</strike> <strike>77</strike> <strike>73</strike> 71 bytes

(Score one extra because we require `-r` flag)

```sed
h
s/./&_/
:
/(\b[^ ]+).*\b\1_/{
s/_(.)/\1_/
t
g
}
s/_(.)/ \1_/
t
s/_//
```

The inner loop tests for a repeated sequence and appends characters as needed until a unique number appears after the separator `_`.  The outer loop moves `_` along.

Expanded, annotated version:

```sed
#!/bin/sed -rf

# Stash original in hold space
h

# Add separator
s/./&_/

:
# If current candidate is a duplicate, ...
/(\b[^ ]+).*\b\1_/{
#  ...then attempt to lengthen it ...
s/_(.)/\1_/
# ... and repeat if we succeeded, ...
t
# ... otherwise, restore original string
g
}
# Insert a space, and move our separator along
s/_(.)/ \1_/
t

# Remove the separator if we still have it
s/_//
```

Comment: You could combine both the `t`'s into one.

Comment: Also `/((\b[^ ]+).*\b\2)_/{` can be rewritten as `/(\b[^ ]+).*\b\1_/{`, no reason for 2 capture groups.

Comment: No problem :), you need to change the reference to `\1` though!

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 57 + 1 = 58 bytes

```
s=''
l={}
$_.chars{|c|l[s<<c]||=s=''}
l[s]||$_=l.keys*' '
```

Uses the command line flag `-p` (or `pl` if your input has a trailing newline). Exploits several traits of Ruby Hash dictionaries: you can safely mutate the string you used to define a key without it changing the key (which doesn't work for other mutable types), `.keys` returns the keys in the order they were inserted, and the `[]||=` operator provides a terse way of branching on whether a given key is already there.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 105 bytes

`f` does it.

```
e""s""=unwords s
e t s""=concat s++t
e t s(c:r)|t&c`elem`s=e(t&c)s r|0<1=e""(s&(t&c))r
a&b=a++[b]
f=e""[]
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 148 bytes

Cool challenge, lots of fun!

```
$x=fgets(STDIN);$w=array();$k='';$l='';for($i=0;$i<strlen($x);$i++){$k.=$x[$i];if(!isset($w[$k])){$l.=$k.' ';$w[$k]=1;$k='';}}echo strlen($k)?$x:$l;
```